# Bootstrap 3 Apply CSS on Mobile View Only

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I' am using Bootstrap 3, In the mobile view I would like to apply some CSS to fix up some bugs on mobile view. I have looked to documentations and Google it. I' am can't seem to find any clue on it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Just use the appropriate media queries in your CSS, eg

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* CSS goes here */
}
```

Bootstrap defines the following widths

- Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px)
- Small devices (tablets, 768px and up)
- Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up)
- Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)

See http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ for some more information on media queries.

Answer (score 18):

There are also responsive utilities, you can add classes to certain elements to either show or hide them at certain viewport sizes.

```
.hidden-xs or .visible-xs
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: This is no longer supported from bootstrap 4. Check my answer below for new versions

Answer (score 5):

You can use responsive display classes  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/ in `Bootstrap 4`

So for example, you want to hide a specific element for only phones (in both portrait & landscape mode or xs and sm), you can do

```
<div class="big_image d-none d-md-block">
</div>
```

What it does is set `display:none` by default and makes it visible only from `md` and above.