# Change H1 size for mobile view only on Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'd like to change the H1 size for the mobile view only within Bootstrap 3.

Any recommendations on how to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried anything...?

Comment: `@media` in CSS will render a specific style given a specific viewport size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Apply CSS on Mobile View Only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827236/bootstrap-3-apply-css-on-mobile-view-only)

Answer (score 0):

normally phones in bootstrap are triggered when screen size is < 768px so you could use media queries to change the font size of h1 for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  h1{
     font-size:3em;
  }    
}
```

example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93gb39Lt/