# how to check browser width of browser in shiny app with shinydashboard and change box width accordingly

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I wanted to detect browser width. And trigger width change in css if it is too small.

Basically, I want to change box width is 50% screen width if mobile and 20$ screen width if it larger than mobile screen

Following is my code

```
box(
      title = "KPI Table"
      ,div(style="display:block;width: 20%;float: left;margin: 0 10px;"
          ,selectInput('slice', 'Time View'
                   , c('Day', 'Week', 'Month', 'Quarter', 'Year')
                   , selected = 'Month'))
      , DT::dataTableOutput('KPITab')
      , status = "primary"
      , width = 12
      , collapsible = TRUE)
    )
```

I want to use javascript to detect change in width and change value 20% to 50% in div .

Thanks

Comment: With jQuery it's `$(window).width()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get browser width using javascript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038727/how-to-get-browser-width-using-javascript-code)

Comment: I don't  have knowlege of shiny or javascript, need little big more guidance

Comment: You should read the answers to the question I linked to, but also note that a responsive framework should address browser width anyway and most components of Shiny are responsive by default. jQuery is a JS library you can include that allows you to detect browser width with the command I gave.

Comment: It is reactive, However, I want to change my input according to my browser width

Comment: Responsive, not reactive. They're different. With a responsive design you don't have to change your code. Go to this link and find the word responsive. http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html If you put your box in a responsive layout it automatically resizes unless you break it by trying to hard-code dimensions.

Comment: What about shinyjs::runjs($(window).width()) ?

Comment: CSS could solve your problem. I don't know CSS. Try to Google css bootstrap mobile. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827236/bootstrap-3-apply-css-on-mobile-view-only

Comment: thanks, CSS has simple hack "width-minimum", which does What I need to do.

Answer (score -1):

Css style has option of "width-minimum" is simple alternative solution.

Comment: So what element to apply to? Example?